# Comparar repetição de valores em cinco variáveis ao mesmo tempo

Tags: php

Gostaria de uma pequena ajuda. tenho um pequeno formulário web onde a pessoas deve selecionar 5 opções em campos HTML SELECT. Ao enviar o formulário, tenho que verificar se alguma das que foram preenchidas (é opcional preencher, mas se preencher, não pode repetir) se repete. Caso alguma opção se repetir, tenho que tratar e mostrar um erro. Se todas forem únicas eu gravo as informações no banco de dados. Segue estrutura do meu php:

```
$var1 = isset($_POST["id_variante1"]) ? $_POST["id_variante1"] : "";
$var2 = isset($_POST["id_variante2"]) ? $_POST["id_variante2"] : "";
$var3 = isset($_POST["id_variante3"]) ? $_POST["id_variante3"] : "";
$var4 = isset($_POST["id_variante4"]) ? $_POST["id_variante4"] : "";
$var5 = isset($_POST["id_variante5"]) ? $_POST["id_variante5"] : "";
```

Há alguma maneira simples de verificar se alguma delas diferente de "vazio" se repete?

Edição:

Edição:

A forma mais simples que achei foi essa, misturando a sugestão do @Igor.
Não é a coisa mais prática do mundo, mas funciona para o que eu preciso:

```
$teste = array_filter($_POST["id_variante[]"]);
if(count(array_unique($teste))<count($teste))
{ 
echo "há duplicatas" 
} else { 
echo "não há duplicatas" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma coisa que eu acho que pode funcionar:

```
$var = array(5);

$var[0] = isset($_POST["id_variante1"]) ? $_POST["id_variante1"] : "";
$var[1] = isset($_POST["id_variante2"]) ? $_POST["id_variante2"] : "";
$var[2] = isset($_POST["id_variante3"]) ? $_POST["id_variante3"] : "";
$var[3] = isset($_POST["id_variante4"]) ? $_POST["id_variante4"] : "";
$var[4] = isset($_POST["id_variante5"]) ? $_POST["id_variante5"] : "";
```

Então tu compara os valores nas posições destes arrays, claro que não seria a forma perfeita de se fazer isso, mas pode funcionar.

Comment: Já pensei nessa solução, até mesmo já enviar como array com id_variante[]. Até agora a solução mais simples que encontrei foi essa:
``` $teste = array_filter($_POST["id_variante[]"]);
if(count(array_unique($teste))<count($teste)) { echo "há duplicatas" } else { echo "não há duplicatas" } ```